Is gravity getting weaker? Do we observe stronger gravitational effects from distant objects?
Just curious. If the many-worlds interpretation is correct,  could effects of gravity be diluted over time?  If so then when we observe distant objects can we see stronger gravity? Could the Higgs field be degraded over time? And one final thought. Could it ever be reversed? So gravity eventually becomes repulsive?

Why would we see stronger gravity from further objects if simultaneously gravity was getting weaker? None of those sentences make any sense.

This question is similar to: What is the proof that the universal constants ($G$, $\hbar$, $\ldots$) are really constant in time and space?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This isn't a site to answer random thoughts that occur to people.  You have two questions in the subject line and another five (!) in the body of the post.  You're supposed to have just one question which you explain clearly so people understand your conceptual problem.

What does MWI have to do with gravity?
